# Remove a specific value from each row of a column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Im trying to remove the .0 present at the end of each number in the column M1 bis.

```
us_m1.head()

    DATE        M1      M1bis
0   1975-01-06  273.4   273400.0
1   1975-01-13  273.7   273700.0
2   1975-01-20  273.8   273800.0
3   1975-01-27  273.7   273700.0
4   1975-02-03  275.2   275200.0
```

I tried this but it is not doing anything, do you have some idea how I could do this ?

```
us_m1['M1bis'].replace(to_replace ='.0',value = 'None',inplace = True)
```

Thanks

Comment: actually those are in `float` format that's why you are having in that format just simply convert them into `int` using `astype`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`us_m1['M1bis'] = us_m1['M1bis'].astype(int)` will change each to int and remove the value.

Comment: This will not work if there is a `NaN` in the column.

Answer (score -1):

If your M1bis column is of type float pandasman solution will solve the issue.

If your column is of type string the following will do:

```
us_m1["M1bis"] = us_m1["M1bis"].apply(lambda x: x.replace(".0", "")
```

`.apply` iterates over each value in the column us_m1["M1bis"]
`lambda x: function(x)` applies a function on each entry (x).
`replace(".0", "")` replaces every `.0` string with an empty one.

Comment: Ah thanks, I removed the duplicate part.